# ERROR:Exception in request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to [host] refused

Tags: oracle, performance

I have some procedures and views consumed as a web services on my Oracle DB, it was working fine and recently due to the increase in requests calls, the consumer applications are receiving the error in the subject

how I can enhance the performance of my XDB to accept the current load? is there is any DB views can show me how much load I currently have?

My DB: 11.2.0.4

Attached are the current configuration file from the following select statement and the result of the XDB_USAGE_CHECK

```
SELECT DBMS_XDB.cfg_get() FROM DUAL;
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AjCAV2gjR5OC7UhVRBNM2mZ1MKKowD_T/view?usp=share_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17hlsDzYdhwg7tu88CpncVLt61OuBxLsL/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please add your code and whatever those links contain to your question. Please don't add links to 3rd party sites.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck